# Outbound Messages java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, timeout, node.js

I am getting a lot of `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` with my Workflow Outbound Messages

It looks like remote server (Node.JS express) works to slow and salesforce breaks connection before getting an answer.

Does anybody know what is the Read Timeout of Outbound Messages, can it be increased somehow?

Comment: did you get an answer on this?